# Why do CSS floats add margins to child elements?

Tags: html, css, margin

Using this example from [MDN's Introduction to CSS layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction), CSS float adds margins to the P and H2 elements. This is the code sample:

```
<h1>2 column layout example</h1>
<div>
  <h2>First column</h2>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus aliquam dolor, eu lacinia lorem placerat vulputate. </p>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Second column</h2>
  <p>Nam vulputate diam nec tempor bibendum. Donec luctus augue eget malesuada ultrices. Phasellus turpis est, posuere sit amet dapibus ut.</p>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS (I added background-color to make it easy to see):

```
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
}
```

If you use exactly the same code minus the floats, there is no top margin on the H2 element and no bottom margin on the P element. The colored DIVs fit tightly around the text.

However, if you do include the floats, not only does the layout of the DIVs change (from stacked to side-by-side, as expected), but a top margin is added to the H2 element and a bottom margin is added to the P element. You can clearly see that the colored DIVs don't fit tightly around the text anymore at the tops and bottoms.

I can remove these margins easily enough with:

```
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It's easily fixed but my question is, why? Why does adding a float cause the automatic insertion of unwanted margins to the child elements? Is this behavior expected or desired? Is it a bug? A feature? It seems odd and unpredictable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default there is some `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` set from the browser on `h2` and `p` tags, and according to MDN - [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the later sibling needs to be cleared past floats).

...

> If there is no border, padding ... The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

...

> Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

Comment: Choosing this as best answer because it lead me to the right answer but from what I can tell, this isn't due to adjacent siblings, but rather, the "parent and first/last child" collapsing margins rule. Also, the note about floated and absolutely positioned elements never collapsing. Now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just before white CSS you can reset all default browser styles. Use some [CSS reseters](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @MatheusAvellar **Thank You !!!**.
_i will pay more attention next time when i write an asnwer._

Comment: Awesome! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with floats, but simply with the browser default styles, plus with "collapsing margins" at the top and bottom of elements. If you open the Firefox browser developer tools, there is a tab labeled "calculated" (or similar, not sure about the exact English expression), which contains a checkbox "brwoser styles". When you check that, you see the browser default styles when examining HTML elements.